# Model not updating when calling another controller on submit click ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form where users can update certain information. When they choose 'Request Invoice' the action should take the new updated model to the specified controller for processing. The routing action is working as expected, the only problem I am facing is, it is still sending the old model to the controller and not the new updated one.

I am still pretty new to ASP.NET Core MVC and any help and guidance will be appreciated.

My view:

```
@model xxx.Models.Modules

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Manage Module";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Modules</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ModuleName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ModuleName" class="form-control" readonly/>
                <span asp-validation-for="ModuleName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NumberOfLicenses" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NumberOfLicenses" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NumberOfLicenses" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NumberOfLicensesUsed" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NumberOfLicensesUsed" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NumberOfLicensesUsed" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NumberOfLicesesAvailable" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NumberOfLicesesAvailable" class="form-control" readonly/>
                <span asp-validation-for="NumberOfLicesesAvailable" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="CompanyId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Request Invoice" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CreateInvoice","XeroOAuth2",Model)'" />
                <input type="submit" value="Request Quote" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("RequestQoute","XeroOAuth2",Model)'" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

My model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace xxx.Models
{
    public class Modules
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ModuleName { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfLicenses { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfLicensesUsed { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfLicesesAvailable { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller action method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateInvoice(Modules modules)
{
    var client = new XeroClient(xconfig);
    await _xero.CreateInvoice(xconfig, modules);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Expected result: on the view when `NumberOfLicenses` gets changed, and the request invoice button is clicked, it should pass through the new model to the controller.

Comment: The `client` variable is not used in the `CreateInvoice` method. You're using `_xero` instead.

Comment: Form is a good one mechanism for sending data to server, but you are using javascript coupled with `Model` property, generated by Razor - this approach doesn't react to values being changed. Try to use separated js-handler for every submit button.

Comment: Hi @MarkBerry, you use the `onclick` event with the `Model`. The razor `Model` will not update dynamically when you change any value in the form.

Comment: The action and everything is working. I can click the button and hit hits the controller. Only problem is, it does not use the updated model. Ex I change the value of NumberOfLicenses but then the original value will still pull through.

Comment: As my previous comment said, it is not possible to dynamically update the `Model` value in your onclick when you change the value, you can F12 in the browser to check the button url, it will render the parameter with value and cannot be changed dynamically. A quick way is just use form submit can work fine, but it seems you want two different button to hit two different action, right? If so, you may need use js to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you use the `onclick` event with the `Model` to send the request. But you need know that the razor `Model` will render the parameter with value when page load(F12 in the browser to check the rendered value of `@Url.Action`), and it will not update the value dynamically when you change the inputs in the form.

Then it seems you want to use different buttons to send request to different action in the same form, you may need use js/jquery to change the form action attribute to achive your requirement.

A simple demo you could follow:

```
@model Modules
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ModuleName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ModuleName" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="ModuleName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NumberOfLicenses" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NumberOfLicenses" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NumberOfLicenses" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NumberOfLicensesUsed" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NumberOfLicensesUsed" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NumberOfLicensesUsed" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NumberOfLicesesAvailable" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NumberOfLicesesAvailable" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="NumberOfLicesesAvailable" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="CompanyId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" value="Request Invoice" class="btn btn-primary" 
                                                onclick="CreateInvoice()" />
                <input type="button" value="Request Quote" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("RequestQoute","XeroOAuth2",Model)'" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS in the view

```
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }

    <script>
        function CreateInvoice() {
            $("form").attr('action', '@Url.Action("CreateInvoice","XeroOAuth2")');
            $("form").submit();
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Tried following the above example. The problem I am receiving is, it does not hit my controller. Results in blank page with all data in the URL.

Comment: Hi @MarkBerry, this js even be same what you did in onclick event with get request. If you said it does not work and do not want the data in the url, I assume that you may not share the correct code with us and guessing your `CreateInvoice` is a [HttpPost] request. Pls share your code current now.